# jQuery: event - not clicked on div

Tags: jquery

I know only the basics of jQuery at the moment, but I am curious on how to make something happen when I click on background.

I tried making an `onClick` event on the background, but whenever I click on the Div - not the background, in which case I don't want to trigger event - it triggers the event. The Div is inside the background's Div.

Comment: show your JS and html..

Comment: Show us the HTML, CSS, and JS.

Comment: Provider your JS, HTML, and CSS preferrably in jsfiddle.com

Comment: Here's a keyword to help you : `event bubbling`. This is some very important concept you'll have to know before going further.

Comment: little hint here -> http://jsfiddle.net/NVvKG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/k4Xmk/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
    This is the text to click
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>This works</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.background').click(function(e){
    if( e.target !== this ) 
       return;
    alert("click!!!");
});
```